# How to turn homogenous differential equation $f(x,y)=dy/dx=x+y$ into the form of $F(y/x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have been trying to rewrite this equation $dy/dx=x+y$  according to the property that my book describes:

“*... thus homogenous functions are of the form: $$dy/dx=F(x/y)$$*”

I am having a lot of difficulty in doing so. The aforementioned definition is used by my book and I want to see if I can determine if it is homogenous this way.

There are a ton of examples which show you can rewrite a differential equation in that form but there are also a lot of other examples where this feat looks nearly impossible. Now if I use the property that a differential equation is homogenous if $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are homogenous functions in the differential equation of form: $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy = 0$$

then I can determine if it’s a homogenous differential equation.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right "homogeneous"? As a linear DE, the homogeneous equation of $y'-y=x$ is $y'-y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is homogeneous if:

$$f(\alpha x, \alpha y) = \alpha^k f(x, y),$$

where $\alpha >0$ and $k$ is constant called "degree of homogeneity".

---

A first order ODE is homogeneous if it has the form:

$$f(x,y)dy = g(x,y)dx,$$

provided that both $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous functions **with the same degree of homogeneity**.

---

Consider the ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x + y.$$

It can be  rewritten as:

$$1 \cdot dy = (x+y) dx.$$

Therefore, let $f(x,y) = 1$ and $g(x,y) = x+ y.$

Notice that $f(x,y) = 1$ is homogeneous. Indeed, we have that $f(\alpha x, \alpha y) = 1 = \alpha^0 f(x, y).$ The degree of homogeneity of $f$ is $k = 0$.

Moreover, notice that $g(x,y) = x+y$ is homogeneous. Indeed, for any $\alpha$, we have that $g(\alpha x, \alpha y) = \alpha(x+y) = \alpha^1 g(x, y).$ The degree of homogeneity of $g$ is $k = 1$.

---

An homogeneous ODE can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),$$

**if the degree of homogeneity of $f$ is equal to the degree of homogeneity of $g$**. Thus, your equation doesn't satisfy this requirement, and hence there is no way to write it in the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

---

**Bonus - a working example**

Consider the following:

$$(2x+y)dx = (4x+5y)dy.$$

It is easy to show that both $f(x,y) = 2x+y$ and $g(x,y) = 4x+5y$ are homogeneous with degree $1$ (try by yourself!).

Notice that the equation can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = \frac{2x+y}{4x+5y}.$$

Now, observe that:

$$\frac{f(\alpha x, \alpha y)}{g(\alpha x,\alpha y)} = \frac{2\alpha x+\alpha y}{4\alpha x+5 \alpha y)} = \frac{\alpha(2x+y)}{\alpha(4x+5y)} = \frac{2x+y}{4x+5y} = \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}.$$

Consider $\alpha = \frac{1}{x}$. You get:

$$\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = \frac{f(\alpha x, \alpha y)}{g(\alpha x,\alpha y)} = \frac{f\left(1, \frac{y}{x}\right)}{g\left(1, \frac{y}{x}\right)} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$$

Then:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = \frac{2+\frac{y}{x}}{4+5\frac{y}{x}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I really wish that property you stated was mentioned in the textbooks I used. I think it is a very important thing to know that a homogenous ODE can only be written in F(y/x) if the degrees of homegeneity of f and g are equal to each other. The way the book I used introduced homogenous differential equations made it seem like that property is true for all homogenous ODE. Thanks again! Really helpful!

Comment: @joshual you are welcome

Comment: Quick question: dy/dx = x+y is in fact a homogenous differential equation by definition right?

Comment: @joshual Thanks for the question. The answer is **NO**. I'm correcting the provided definition. The point is that the ODE has the form $f(x,y)dy = g(x,y)dx$, where both $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous **with the same degree**.

Comment: Thank you so much! Homogenous function but not homogenous ODE,.